# Converting object into an array which contains object as element 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

From a Json file I get elements (th) that are either a single object or an array with multiple objects. In the first case I want to convert it to an array with one element, because I want to handle both cases in the same way. I did:

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.apply(th) !== '[object Array]' ) {
    var th1 = th;
    th = new Array();
    th[0] = th1;
}
```

Which seems to work, but looks a bit complicated. Is there a shorter solution?

Comment: The Array literal, my friend. `th = [th];` or just `th = new Array(th);` but the literal is shorter.

Comment: @JoeSimmons Also safer : `var Array = {}`

Comment: Why would he do `Array = {}`? I get how it could be safer, but it would be such a rare case... why even confuse people with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. 
the trick is  :

```
var CurrentlyNotAnArrayButGoingtoBe=[CurrentlyNotAnArrayButGoingtoBe];
```

so :

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.apply(th) !== '[object Array]' ) {
     th = [th];

}
```

Also notice that

`th = new Array(th);` is not safe

someone can do :

`Array = {}` and there you go with exception when `th = new Array(th)`

Comment: Well, if this "someone" is silly enough, they also could make `Object.prototype.toString=banana`. Nothing in Javascript is "safe" in this sense.

Comment: @thg435 that someone could be 3'rd party js code you set in your page. there are 2 monster in web world : cross domain issue , and third party js.